# Difference Between Error Messages on Duplicate Campaign Member Insert

Tags: error-messages, campaign, campaign-member

I recently imported Campaign Members to two Campaigns. I see the following errors for a handful of records.

```
ERROR: Attempted to add an entity '0036100000abcde' to a campaign '70161000000abcd' more than once.
```

and

```
ERROR: This entity is already a member of this campaign
```

Is there a difference between these error messages?

Comment: Late to the party. I don't have an answer to this rather a theory. You get the first one if you are inserting two members at once, same contact and same campaign. And the second one in case one is already existing in Salesforce and you attempt to insert new one.